# IndexPath.row value is not stored

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, indexing

Im trying to store the indexPath.row value but on the next view Im getting 0.

In selectedRecipiesViewController I always get a zero. Here is my code.

**MainRecipieViewController.h**

```
@property (assign)   int storageString ;
```

**MainRecipieViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.selectedRecipiesViewController) {
        self.selectedRecipiesViewController = [[[SelectedRecipiesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectedRecipiesViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {

        self.selectedRecipiesViewController.passingArray = soupArray; 
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {

        self.selectedRecipiesViewController.passingArray = seaFoodArray;
    }      
    if (indexPath.row ==2) {
        self.selectedRecipiesViewController.passingArray = meatMuttonArray;
    } 

    storageString = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"storageString %i",storageString);


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.selectedRecipiesViewController animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

**SelectedRecipiesViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     NSLog(@"next view %i" ,self.vc.storageString);
   }
```

Comment: you are not assigning to the property of `selectedRecipiesViewController` but you are assigning value to the current viewController's property

Comment: self.selectedRecipesViewController.storageString = storageString; if you prefer dot notation.

Comment: I would also add that instead of having 3 if conditions you should have one if-elseif-elseif condition, since after the first successful match occurs you would not need to hit any condition following the match.

Comment: @MichaelKellyReneer Good point.  Could also use a `switch` statement.

Comment: And taking a second look, there is no reason to be calling `[tableView reloadData];` since your not modifying the `ainRecipieViewController` list of data. You would likely, need to call `reloadData` on `self.selectedRecipiesViewController`, but I would probably do that in that view controllers `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't appear that you're setting it in the target view controller.  Also, it seems that you've created the property `storageString` in the incorrect header file (`MainRecipieViewController.h`).

#### SelectedRecipiesViewController.h

```
@property (assign) int storageString;
```

Then try using this before you push the view controller:

```
[self.selectedRecipesViewController setStorageString:indexPath.row];
```

Finally...

#### SelectedRecipiesViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"next view %i", self.storageString);
}
```